# About launching LXC Containers and their IP assignment

Tags: networking, server, dhcp, lxc

i am playing around with LXD and their Containers. I configured my LXD init like this:

> ...
> Would you like to create a new local network bridge? (yes/no) [default=yes]: no
> Would you like to configure LXD to use an existing bridge or host interface? (yes/no) [default=no]: yes
> Name of the existing bridge or host interface: eth0
> Would you like LXD to be available over the network? (yes/no) [default=no]: yes
> Address to bind LXD to (not including port) [default=all]: default
> Port to bind LXD to [default=8443]: default
> ...

so LXD created a Profile for me:

> name: eth0
> nictype: macvlan
> parent: eth0
> type: nic

My Routers IP is 10.0.1.1 
some times when i start a new container it does not assign a correct IP from my Router. Or it will, but not really.

e.g. i launch Container1 and it gets the IP if i look into lxc list 192.168.10.133 (where the last digit matches the assigned IP from my Router, if i look into the connected devices on my Router there is shown Container1 with IP 10.0.1.133.)

But the problem is i can not ping the Container. Not from my Network and also not from my LXD Host.

I can still access by lxc shell Container1, additionally the Container has Internet Access BUT it can not ping my Router (lol).

If i start 10 Containers (no matter if i start one and wait a bit or start them in a bunch) its like 3 to 5 which get a "wrong" IP. One could say, just launch another Container but i'd like to understand this circumstance.
Can anyone explain this ?

Comment: How did you create this bridge? Did you just tell LXC to use your eth0 or did you previously create a bridge called eth0?